# Java script change button class based upon selection

Tags: javascript

I have an element that I want to change the class based on the dropdown selection.

```
<div class="col-sm">
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button class="accordion-button" role="alert" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" id="question-1">
                Does the project land in our Tiered entry levels?
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
             <div class="accordion-body">
                <div class="col-sm">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        {{ form.subject.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.form.project_tier_entry_level.id_for_label }}"></label>
                        {{ form.project_tier_entry_level }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                {{ form.subject.errors }}
                                {{ form.project_tier_entry_level_notes }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
         </div>
```

On this line
`<button class="accordion-button" role="alert" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" id="question-1">`

I want to change  `class="accordion-button"` to `accordion-button alert alert-success`

The default value for the select box is
`---------` so when this changes to anything other than the default I'd like to class to be changed.

I've been trying to work this out, but i can't get this to work:

```
document.getElementById('accordionExample').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.tagName === "SELECT" && tgt.id.startsWith("question-")) { 
      const yes = tgt.value === "Yes"
      const statusBadge = tgt.previousElementSibling;
      statusBadge.classList.toggle("accordion-button alert alert-success", !'---------')
    }
  });
```

Im using Django to render the select box, so rendered it looks like this

```
<label for=""></label>
    <select name="project_tier_entry_level" class="form-select" id="id_project_tier_entry_level">
        <option value="" selected>---------</option>
        <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
        <option value="Unknown">Unknown</option>
</select>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you define `onchange` on the `select` elemlent?

Comment: There are probably 50 of these that i want to change every time one is selected. If I change to `onchange` on the `select` element, would I need to do this for each one?

Comment: you mean there is one `.accordion-button` and 50 `select`? or there are 50 boxes that every box has it's own `.accordion-button` and `select`?

Comment: there are 50 boxes that every box has it's own .accordion-button and select?